# A quick way to determine whether a number is prime by hand?

Tags: prime-numbers

I would like to know how to determine by hand whether a number is prime to help me in math contests.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Why is it important for you to do this by hand?

Comment: Well, when I'm participating in a math contest XD

Comment: @zscoder If you participate to a math contest, you should know immediately that $4\,294\,967\,297$ is not prime.

Comment: composite (fermat Number)

Comment: All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$.

Comment: There are a few techniques that can be used, but nothing at all general. It is for something that the "determine if $n$ is prime" algorithms are still an active area of research.

Comment: @egreg my hero. As vonbrand says, this is an active area of research (and one I personally hope isn't resolved anytime soon). Much of cryptology relies on the difficulty of these problems.

Comment: @Lucian, but the [converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788721/how-to-determine-numbers-in-the-form-6n1-that-are-not-prime) isn't true, which is what is needed to test here (e.g. $25$ is of the form $6n + 1$ but it's NOT prime).

Comment: @Leponzo: Common people usually check for primes among odd numbers; searching for them among numbers of the form $6n\pm1$ reduces the effort from half to a third.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no super-fast way to determine if an arbitrary number is prime by hand. However, you can often quickly determine when a number *isn't* prime, which is often good enough, especially if you are only dealing with smallish numbers, as you often are in math competitions.

- If a number ends in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6 or 8 then it's not prime (except for 2 and 5)
- If the sum of the digits is a multiple of 3, then the number is not prime (except for 3)

Those two rules knock about nearly 75% of numbers.

For numbers below 100, the only false positives are $49=7^2$, $77=7\cdot 11$ and $91=7\cdot 13$ which you can learn.

#### Divisibility by 7

A number of the form $10x+y$ is divisible by 7 exactly when $x-2y$ is divisible by 7. This allows you to quickly reduce the size of a number until you reach a number that obviously is or isn't a multiple of 7. For example, consider $n=847 = 84\times 10 + 7$. Then $x-2y$ is $84 - 14 = 70$ which is obviously divisible by 7, so 847 is also divisible by 7.

#### Divisibility by 11

There is also a simple test for multiples of 11 - starting from the units place, add the first digit, subtract the next digit, add the next one and so on. If you end up with a negative number, treat it as positive. If the result is a multiple of 11, so is the original number.

For example, take $n=539$. You calculate $9-3+5=11$, which is a multiple of 11, and so 539 is a multiple of 11.

Using these rules to check for divisibility by 2, 3, 5, 7 and 11 the only false positive less than 200 is 169, which is easy to remember as it is $13^2$. The only false positives below 300 are $221=13\times 17$, $247=13\times 19$, $289=17^2$ and $299=13\times 23$.

**Edit:** Just for fun, here's a graph of how many false positives there are for a given upper bound. This chart shows that with four rules and a list of 13 exceptions, you can correctly find whether any number under 500 is prime or not in... probably 20-30 seconds?

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, whats the software you used to make that graph?

Comment: The graph (and the calculation) were done in Matlab.

Answer (score 7):

To determine if $n$ is prime:

1. Find the biggest perfect square $k^2 \le n$.
2. Write out all the primes less than or equal to $k$.
3. Test if $n$ is divisible by each of said primes on your list.

   - If $n$ is divisible by any of the primes, $n$ is not prime.
   - If $n$ is divisible by none of the primes, $n$ is prime.

Comment: This is nice, but is there a faster one? (I commonly use this to determine primality)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: If you are doing it by hand read [this one.](https://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/DORSEY-F.PDF)

You can try [running some probabilistic primality tests,
reading this [article](https://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/DORSEY-F.PDF) for some more info on primality tests, or reading this [article](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1999-jacm.pdf) on using elliptic curves.

Without any more information, it's hard to know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I think this test is only possible with a computer

Comment: www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/DORSEY-F.PDF there are some you can do by hand here, such as the one based on fermat's little theorem