# How to determine numbers in the form (6n+1) that are NOT prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In another post, [Show that every prime p>3 is either of the form 6n+1 or of the form 6n+5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/show-that-every-prime-p3-is-either-of-the-form-6n1-or-of-the-form-6n5), it was shown that primes are in the form $(6n+1)$ or $(6n+5)$.

How do you determine if a number in the form $(6n+1)$ is NOT prime?  Clearly $25, 121, 289, 529,$ etc., are not prime ($5 \times 5, 11 \times 11, 17 \times 17, 23x23$).

In general, numbers in the form $(6n+1)$ are not prime when they have the factors $(6q-1)(6q-1)$; this is easy to see why when you multiply out the quadratic factors.

In another post, [6n+1 and 6n−1 prime format](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895992/6n1-and-6n-1-prime-format), there is a sieve that possibly could be adapted to show values that would not be prime; however, is there a general proof showing all numbers that are not prime and in the form $(6n+1)$?

P.S.  Thanks to everyone who has contributed to this great site.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741007/arithmetic-sequence-where-every-term-is-prime

Answer (score 1):

By comparing the numbers up to 200, I've established some rules which I am sure hold. Numbers of the form $6n+1$ are not prime if they are also of any of these forms:
Note $p,q\in\Bbb Z$
$$(6p-1)^2$$
$$(6p+1)^2$$
$$(6p-1)(6q-1)$$
$$(6p+1)(6q+1)$$

Comment: To prove that this holds in general, it's sufficient to note that every odd number that is not divisible by $3$ (i.e., of the form $6p \pm 1$ for $p > 0$) is the product of odd primes greater than $3$; that every odd prime greater than $3$ is not divisible by $3$, and hence is of the form $(6q \pm 1)$ and, finally, that the multiplying two numbers in that form gives a product in the same form.  For instance, $(6p+1)(6q+1) = 6(6pq+p+q) + 1$.

Comment: Thx for the reply.  In general, numbers in the form (6n+1) are not prime when they have the factors (6q−1)(6q−1); this is easy to see why when you multiply out the quadratic factors.  Are there any other algebraic forms that would show values of 6n+1 that are not prime?

Comment: Wow fabio , it is an amazing analysis